# Alsa to run as root

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am attempting to play a sound file in my python code on raspberry pi.  Unfortuantley some libraries that I am using (rover kit) require to run as Root.  When I try to play the audio file then I get the error below.  It is clear that the issue is running as root but unfortunatley one of my other libraries is requiring that I run as root.

Is there any way to get audio to play from the root user?

Thank you.

Here is my python code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

import os

class JohnnyAudio():

    def __init__(self):
        self.missle = AudioSegment.from_wav("Code/Server/mw2missillaunch.wav")

    def playMissle(self):
        play(self.missle)
```

And the console output:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
Input #0, wav, from '/tmp/tmpfu0s_02d.wav':   0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: 00:00:02.34, bitrate: 176 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 176 kb/s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
SDL_OpenAudio (1 channels, 22050 Hz): ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory
No more combinations to try, audio open failed
Failed to open file '/tmp/tmpfu0s_02d.wav' or configure filtergraph
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   

        Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 176 kb/s
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
```

Permissions on the file trying to run:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 51708 Aug 23  2012 mw2missillaunch.wav
```

Comment: Please include your code and show permissions as well.

Comment: Thank you, I added my code and permissions

Answer (score 1):

There is, but I could only do it once on a pi3.

It was based on this code:
https://github.com/shivasiddharth/PulseAudio-System-Wide

which does not seem to work any more for me anyway.